# Netbeans 7 code completion doesn't work with Play framework

Tags: netbeans, playframework

I've created Play appliacion with *play new project* command, and then *play netbeansify project*. I've opened the poject, and Ctrl+space shows "no suggestions" in my Application.java, and there is a wrench badge and "Needs to be compiled" message next to each file.

Is it possible to make Netbeans work with play apps?

Comment: Now in models.User class Netbeans says that package javax.persisnece doesn't exist. In controller class everything looks good.

Comment: I use netbeans.  Never had an issue.  Do a play clean.  play deps --sync.  play netbeansify.  You should be good to go.

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda does Drew's solution worked for you ?